# Trigger Auto-tab when MaxLength is Reached(asp:TextBox)?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I have 2 text box control . one of length 6 another of 2 . Both accepts numbers only. I want to move to second textbox (kind of Tab functionality) when first one is reached 6 digit number.Any Help?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function change(obj, l) {
                var txt = obj.value;

                if (txt.length == l) {
                    document.getElementById("<%=txtSearchSchoolBranchDOECode.ClientID %>").focus();
                }
            }
</script>

    <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchSchoolDOECode" MaxLength="6" Style="width: 75px;" runat="server" onkeyup="change(this,6)"
                                                CssClass="text"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="txtSearchSchoolDOECode_FilteredTextBoxExtender" runat="server"
                                                Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtSearchSchoolDOECode" FilterType="Numbers">
                                            </asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
                                            -
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchSchoolBranchDOECode" MaxLength="2" Style="width: 25px;"
                                            runat="server" CssClass="text"></asp:TextBox>
                                            <asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="txtSearchSchoolBranchDOECode_FilteredTextBoxExtender1" runat="server"
                                                Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtSearchSchoolBranchDOECode" FilterType="Numbers">
                                            </asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
</td>
```

My only problem here , Shift Tab is not working when I already have 6 digit number in textbox 1 . also arrow keys are not working in keyboard as expected ..

Comment: I have used oninput (HTML 5 supported ) instead of onkeyup and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have used oninput (HTML 5 supported ) instead of onkeyup and it worked as expected.